# Angular Dart 2.0 with multiple components

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have three components in Angular Dart 2.0 which are menu,company,address.. Which is the best method to bootstrap this.. In a single `main.dart` file or using import of every component.dart file to main file and each one bootstrap. My code is given below please help
Menu.dart

```
@Component(
    selector: 'menu'
)

@View(
    templateUrl: 'lib/menu.html'
)
class Menu{

}
```

Company.dart

```
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
@Component(
    selector: 'company'
)

@View(
    templateUrl: 'lib/company.html'
)

class Company{

}
```

How can I define the main Function

```
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:angular2/src/reflection/reflection.dart' show reflector;
import 'package:angular2/src/reflection/reflection_capabilities.dart'
show ReflectionCapabilities;

import 'lib/menu.dart';
import 'lib/company.dart';
import 'lib/address.dart';
main() {
  reflector.reflectionCapabilities = new ReflectionCapabilities();
  bootstrap(Menu);
  bootstrap(Company);
  bootstrap(Address);

}
```

Is this a correct method

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `bootstrap()` is root component of the polymer application. You probably won't create 3 independent Angular applications in your page.

Create an additional application component and pass it to bootstrap

```
bootstrap(Application);
```

If you add all code in one file or split it to a file per component is just a preference.